# R: Change position of x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axis, logarithm

I'm trying to graph a dodged barplot in ggplot2 with a log scale on the y axis. But when I add `scale_y_log10()` to my code, R centers the x axis around 1.0 instead of 0. How can I move the x axis to be at y = 0 so that none of my data < 1.0 appear to be negative?

Here's my code:

```
snag_means
        year LMU  mean.BA.ha    
1       1911   1  0.11219519  
2       1911   2  0.11921667  
3       1911   3  0.07807921  
4       1911   4  0.04811538  
5       1911   5  0.15444167  
6       1911   6  0.02894872 
7  2005-2007   1  5.48898500 
8  2005-2007   2  5.56879565 
9  2005-2007   3  7.51420667 
10 2005-2007   4  2.74502500 
11 2005-2007   5 10.16307419 
12 2005-2007   6  2.91587692 

snag_mean_BA <- ggplot(data = snag_means, 
                       aes(x = LMU, y = mean.BA.ha, fill = year, width = .8)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  labs(title = "Mean Snag Basal Area by Topography", 
       y = expression("Mean Basal Area (" ~ m^{2} ~ ha^{-1} ~ ")"), 
       x = "LMU", fill = "Year") + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("1911", "2005-2007"), values = c("gray31", "gray65")) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 6, by = 1)) + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

Graph `snag_mean_BA`:

[image]

Comment: For any `x < 1`, `log(x) < 0`, so maybe you don't want to use a log-scale. You may, however, rescale your data and make custom y-ticks

Comment: This ended up working out best for what I needed to do - I rescaled by multiplying my data by 100 then added `scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000))`

Comment: Add your comment as an answer (yes, [you can answer your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the `scale_y_log10()` at the end, and inside `aes` to log-transform the data before with  `y = log10(mean.BA.ha)`

```
ggplot(data = snag_means, aes(x = LMU, y = log10(mean.BA.ha), fill = year, width = .8)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  labs(title = "Mean Snag Basal Area by Topography", 
       y = expression("Mean Basal Area (" ~ m^{2} ~ ha^{-1} ~ ")"), 
       x = "LMU", fill = "Year") + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("1911", "2005-2007"), values = c("gray31", "gray65")) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 6, by = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you scale your data so that none of the values are less than 1 you can get (what I believe to be) the desired outcome.

```
snag_means$mean.BA.ha <- snag_means$mean.BA.ha + 1

snag_mean_BA <- ggplot(data = snag_means, aes(x = LMU, y = 
mean.BA.ha, fill = year, width = .8)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
position = "dodge") + labs(title = "Mean Snag Basal Area by
Topography", y = expression("Mean Basal Area (" ~ m^{2} ~ ha^{-1} ~ 
")"), x = "LMU", fill = "Year") + scale_fill_manual(breaks = 
c("1911", "2005-2007"), values = c("gray31", "gray65")) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 6, by = 1)) + scale_y_log10()

snag_mean_BA
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get your desired output by *not* using `scale_y_log10()` but `scale_y_sqrt()`:

```
snag_mean_BA2 <- ggplot(data=snag_means, aes(x=LMU, y=mean.BA.ha, fill=year, width=0.8)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=as.character(unique(snag_means$year)), values=c('gray31','gray65')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,6,by=1)) +
  scale_y_sqrt()
print(snag_mean_BA2)
```

[image]